# Converting JsonValue to domain object

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have an API call as listed below:

```
JsonValue result = api.GET("/chart/" + problemList.PatientMRN.ToString() + "/problems", problemInfo);
string resultString = result.ToString();
```

Note: I am referring to System.Json.JsonValue

Alternative Approach (using JavaScriptSerializer )

```
Rootobject_Labresult objGResponse = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Rootobject_Labresult>(resultString);
```

From the string in Json, I created corresponding classes (using Paste Special in Visual Studio edit menu).

```
public class Rootobject_Labresult
{
    public Labresult[] labresults { get; set; }
    public int totalcount { get; set; }
}

public class Labresult
{
    public string createddate { get; set; }
    public DateTime createddatetime { get; set; }
    public string departmentid { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

But when I create an array, I am getting following error.

```
Labresult[] labresults = result[0];  
////Error: cannot implicitly convert type System.Json.JsonValue to Labresult
```

What is the best way to convert **JsonValue** to the domain object (Labresult) ?

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json.jsonvalue) JsonValue? Also, what's `api.GET`?

Comment: whats the value of `result[0]`? shouldn't it be `result[0].labresults`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I am referring to System.Json.JsonValue. api.GET is a wrapper to call API.

Comment: What's the input JSON you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way to convert from string/System.Json.JsonValue to DotNet Object using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

All you need is the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq namespace and you can do all the conversation with single line of code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var result = JToken.Parse(jsonVal.ToString()).ToObject<Rootobject_Labresult>();
```

I have created a example here.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/N2VfKl

Here is another example for object conversation using Json.NET
https://dotnetfiddle.net/rAkx7m

Json.Net also allow you to work with the json object without declare the class.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZIA8BV

Answer (score 15):

This could have also been done simpler using Json.Net

[`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> Method (String)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm)

```
//...code removed for brevity
string json = result.ToString();
Rootobject_Labresult rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject_Labresult>(json);
Labresult[] labresults = rootObject.labresults;
```

From there you should be able to extract the desired domain values.

And as simple as that was you could have created an extension

```
public static class JsonValueExtensions {
    public static T ToObject<T>(this JsonValue value) {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

which reduces the original code even further

```
//...code removed for brevity
Rootobject_Labresult rootObject = result.ToObject<Rootobject_Labresult>();
Labresult[] labresults = rootObject.labresults;
```

The assumption being that `result` in the above snippet example is an instance of `JsonValue`